# ComboBox with multiple columns?

Tags: c#, forms

I would like a dropdown list (comboBox) that displays not just one column but two (or more).

I have seen examples that concatenates two values to one, and just displays that. But that is a bit ugly. The separator between the two values wont line up at column boundaries, when you have text of different length in the list. Therefore I would like to avoid concatenating, and actually display two separate values in two separate columns. How do I do this?

Ugly:

```
  Johnnie | Doe
  John | Smith
```

Nice:

```
  Johnnie | Doe
  John    | Smith
```

Edit: I went with a ListView instead of a dropdown list. It supports multiple columns cleanly.

Comment: Checkout Telerik RadMultiColumnComboBox

Comment: Thanks, but isnt there a standard way to do this without relying on a 3rd party library?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built in way to do it easily. The standard way to do that is without third party is by replacing OnPaint event. But to do so you may need learn to a couple of things about GDI+ and System.Drawing items, which is more painful... :(

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll just stick with the ugly way then.

Comment: There is one *non*-standard way to work around with some cost. Choose a font type which has constant width for each character (such as notepad's) and then you could measure each word length in column and make use of string.PadRight to fill up the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build the combobox programmatically and have the strings written out (or build a custom method to do so) in such a way that your divider is always at the same location.

Probably something like get the longest length of first name, add 1, then do a string replace with enough spaces to fill before the separator in each name that is shorter.

Comment: Unfortunately I hear multiple spaces will automatically be collapsed into one. Edit: No I was wrong. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: The drawback though is I need to use a fixed width font. I think I'll just use a one row scrollable ListView instead of a dropdown. I know I can display multiple columns properly in that.

Comment: Yeah, there's no good way to do this without a fixed width font.  There are some pretty nice ones out there, though.  I've become a huge fan of Hack:  http://sourcefoundry.org/hack/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do an ownerdraw for this ... see [ComboBox.DrawMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx)  for an example of how to go about it.